# How to create schedule in Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-models

So, I want to create a schedule of training in Django. My DB models looks

> models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone


class Coach(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Пользователь", related_name="coach")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to="coach_avatars/", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.get_full_name()

class TypeOfTraining(models.Model):
    coach = models.ForeignKey(Coach, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="training_type")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    price = models.FloatField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class TrainingSchedule(models.Model):
    coach = models.ForeignKey(Coach, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    training_type = models.ForeignKey(TypeOfTraining, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_at = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

how do I display data from the database in html form that looks like an image?
[example: how looks schedule on HTML page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtaou.png)

I have done HTML template. but I haven't how to show data from DB in my template.

P.S. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django basically follows an MVC pattern. You have the model defined here, the view is achieved by a template (i.e. `dashboard.html`) and the controller could be a `Form` in your project. Along these lines:

Your `dashboard.py`:

```py
from django import forms
from .models import Coach, TypeOfTraining, TrainingSchedule

class DashboardForm(forms.Form):
    def dashboard(request):
        # Extract data from your models here.
        return render(
            request,
            "dashboard.html",
            {
                "form": form,
                "weight_loss_name": some_name,
                "weight_loss_amount": some_weight_loss,
            })
```

And your `dashboard.html`:

```html
<!-- header and navigation and what not -->
<section class="weightloss">
  <h2>Weight Loss</h2>
  <div class="person">{{ weight_loss_name }}</div>
  <div class="amount">{{ some_weight_loss }}</div>
</section>
<!-- rest of the page -->
```